# Navigating to a url using a winforms webbrowser in a wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, .net-4.0

I'm building a WPF application which contains a WebBrowser.  I would like to use the `Document.GetElementByID` method with the webbrowser, and my understanding is that the easiest way to do this in WPF is to use the winforms webbrowser and WindowsFormsIntegration (If there's a better way please let me know)

I'm having a problem navigating to the URL.  Running the program in debug mode does not throw any errors, and stepping over the navigate code still leaves my webbrowser with the following properties:

```
wb1.ReadyState = Uninitialized
wb1.Url = null
```

Am I missing something for navigating to the url?  Can I use the `Document.GetElementById` methods in a WPF webbrowser?

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="my program's main window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
...
<WindowsFormsHost Name="wfh">
    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        <wf:WebBrowser/>
    </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Code:

```
var wb1 = wfh.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;
wb1.Navigate("my url here");
while (wb1.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    // this loop never ends because neither readystate nor wb1.Url ever change
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` (from Assembies > Extensions) to your project. Then use the WPF WebBrowser control and cast its `Document` property to `HTMLDocument`:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Navigated="WebBrowserNavigated" />
```

Code behind:

```
using mshtml;
...

webBrowser.Navigate("...");
...

private void WebBrowserNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var document = webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
    ...
}
```